# moving information from one csv file to another

Tags: javascript, node.js, csv

I need to read the content of a csv file, split the information in the cells into lines, and then export all those new lines into an empty csv file. The code below successfully splits the lines like I need them but it doesn't copy the lines into columns but rather one long row and skips most of the information. All I need is help with copying json objects line by line into an empty csv file. Here is my code:

```
var csv = require ('fast-csv');
var fs = require('fs');
var json2csv = require('json2csv');
csv.
fromPath("/home/juan/analysts.csv")
.on("data", function(data){
    var expertise = data[1];
    var line = expertise.split(/[\n,]/);
    for(i=0; i<line.length; i++){
        var info = {
            experience: line[i]
        };
        return info
        json2csv(info, function(err, doc){
            if(err) console.log(err);
            fs.writeFile('/home/juan/expertise.csv', doc, function(err){
                if(err) throw err;
                console.log('file saved');
            });
        });
    };
})
```

Comment: Can you post the JSON what you have splitted??

Answer (score 0):

If the output csv file is coming as one long string than you are missing the new line char at the end of each line "\n"...depending on the formatting the columns will be defined by commas or tabs but rows need an end of line char.

Basically you are extracting correctly line by line "var line = expertise.split(/[\n,]/);" but it seems that you need to also return it back for each line

I think it's the bit: experience: line[i]....try... experience: line[i] + "\n"